# Copy the content of the bin folder into a specific folder

Tags: msbuild

So far I have this,but it's not working.

```
  <Target Name="AfterBuild">
        <Copy SourceFiles="bin\" DestinationFolder="C:\temp\appServer\"></Copy>
  </Target>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this :

```
<ItemGroup>
    <BinFiles Include="bin\**\*.*"/>
</ItemGroup>

<Target Name="AfterBuild">
    <Copy SourceFiles="@(BinFiles)" 
          DestinationFolder="C:\temp\appServer\"/>
</Target>
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the MSBuild Copy task doesn't take a directory for SourceFiles, but instead a list of files to copy.

Check out the MSDN article here for a simple example:

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3e54c37h.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a file wildcard.

```
<Target Name="AfterBuild">
     <Copy SourceFiles="bin\*.*" DestinationFolder="C:\temp\appServer\"></Copy>
</Target>
```

Comment: This gives the same result as the OP.